# 'TypeError: 'int' object is not callable' when comparing readings 5 seconds apart

Tags: python-2.7, raspbian, adafruit

Setting up a raspberry Pi with a dht22 sensor to automatically turn on a shower light.  I can't seem to get the script to read the sensor, wait 5 seconds and read it again and then do stuff if the reading has changed.  I am not a programmer and have mucked this together with help from friends and lots of google searches, but ultimately I have no clue what I am doing.

I have a script that turns the light on based on the humidity reading above X however as relative humidity changes the script is not as accurate as i would like.

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import Adafruit_DHT
sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22
pin = 17
import time
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.IN)                    #Read output from PIR motion sensor
time.sleep(2)                            #Waiting 2 seconds for the sensor to initiate

state=None
i=None
t2=None
t=None
d=5.0
while True:
#read humidity and store, wait 5 seocnds and read/store again
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin) #takes reading from the sensor
    t='{1:0.1f}'.format(temperature, humidity) #takes the humidity reading and commits to 'h'
    time.sleep=5
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)
    t2='{1:0.1f}'.format(temperature, humidity)
#if the second reading is 5 or more that the first set the state to 1
    if t2 >= str(5.0+(float(t))):
        state=1                         #sets 'state' to 1 if the humidity is high
    else:
#If the second reading is 3 less that the first set the state to 0 
        t2 <= str((float(t)-3.0))
        state=0                         #sets 'state' to 0 if humidity is not high
#storing state as 'i' and trying to do a check loop
    if i == state:                        #state didn't change
        print "holding", t, i
        time.sleep(2)
#what to do if 'i' chnages
    else:
        i = state                          #if the states doesn't  match  set 'i'  to equal 'state'
        if i == 1:                         #what to do if 'state' is '1'
            print "Showering",t,t2,i
            time.sleep(2)
                                                                                            #end of curl
        else:                             #what to do if 'state' is '0'
            print "not showering",t,t2,i
            time.sleep(2)
time.sleep(2)
```

Expected s it will keep printing the state based on changes

what I actually get is this:

sudo python humitest.py
not showering 45.3 45.3 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "humitest.py", line 67, in 
    time.sleep(2)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import Adafruit_DHT
sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22
pin = 17
import time
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.IN)                    #Read output from PIR motion sensor
time.sleep(2)                            #Waiting 2 seconds for the sensor to initiate

state=None
i=None
t2=None
t=None
d=5.0
while True:
#read humidity and store, wait 5 seocnds and read/store again
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin) #takes reading from the sensor
    t='{1:0.1f}'.format(temperature, humidity) #takes the humidity reading and commits to 'h'

    #time.sleep=5 # This line is your problem. What are you trying to do?

    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)
    t2='{1:0.1f}'.format(temperature, humidity)
#if the second reading is 5 or more that the first set the state to 1
    if t2 >= str(5.0+(float(t))):
        state=1                         #sets 'state' to 1 if the humidity is high
    else:
#If the second reading is 3 less that the first set the state to 0 
        t2 <= str((float(t)-3.0))
        state=0                         #sets 'state' to 0 if humidity is not high
#storing state as 'i' and trying to do a check loop
    if i == state:                        #state didn't change
        print "holding", t, i
        time.sleep(2)
#what to do if 'i' chnages
    else:
        i = state                          #if the states doesn't  match  set 'i'  to equal 'state'
        if i == 1:                         #what to do if 'state' is '1'
            print "Showering",t,t2,i
            time.sleep(2)
                                                                                            #end of curl
        else:                             #what to do if 'state' is '0'
            print "not showering",t,t2,i
            time.sleep(2)
time.sleep(2)
```

The line `time.sleep=5` is your problem. Why are you setting the attribute "sleep", which is normally a function, to the int 5? Did you mean `time.sleep(5)`? You get the error because you reassign the attribute "sleep" to 5, and then you try to invoke 5, as in 5(), later on when you do `time.sleep(2)` which of course it not valid.

Comment: You are a god - I have been staring a this for the past 2 days trying to see where the err of my ways was!  It is indeed supposed to be time.wait(5)!!!